# Deserialize response from API using custom class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, c#-4.0

I am receiving the json response of below format from an api. I am trying to deserialze it with custom class.

```
{
    "TraceEvent": {
        "Attributes": {
            "Commodity": "APPLES",
            "Variety": "Green"
        },
        "Codes": [{
                "devicename": "",
                "code": "901491877572115",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-15T19:33:29.4418926+05:30"
            }, {
                "devicename": "",
                "code": "6657287134488755",
                "timestamp": "2018-02-15T19:33:29.4418926+05:30"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is my custom class used for deserialize

```
public class EventContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("TraceEvent")]
    public TraceEvent TraceEvent { get; set; }
} 

public class TraceEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public TraceAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("codes")]
    public TraceCodes Codes { get; set; }
}

public class TraceAttributes
{
    [JsonProperty("commodity")]
    public string Commodity { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("variety")]
    public string Variety { get; set; }
}

public class TraceCodes
{

    public TraceCodes()
    {
        Codes = new List<TraceCode>();
    }
    [JsonProperty("Codes")]
    public List<TraceCode> Codes { get; set; }
}

public class TraceCode
{
    [JsonProperty("devicename")]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

In the receiver side, i am getting null for the `Codes`. Plesae refer my debug screen in api receiver code,

[image]

Can any one tell me how to rewrite my custom class to deserialize the Codes list from JSON api

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you deserialize?

Comment: I feel like you'd be better of making either a custom modelbinder if you use asp.net mvc model binding, or a custom jsonconverter if you use JSON.NET to deserialize.

Comment: You provide a class, but how does it relate to `EventContainer`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman using custom class to bind the JSON attribute to class

Comment: But where does Newtonsoft JSON come in to play?

Comment: @john EventContainer is a class which holds entire json attribute of TraceEvents

Comment: What? That sentence makes little sense. Please add the class definition to your question.

Comment: JSON.Net will not automatically deserialize your model using FromBody unless you have explicitly told your model binding code to do so

Comment: It may not be the solution you are after, but you may be better off reading the input stream and deserializing the string content yourself, it will be much less code imo

Comment: Json says "TraceEvents" and code says "TraceEvent"

Comment: @john I added my entire Model code. Please review.

Comment: Also in the JSON Codes is an array.

Comment: **TraceCodes** should be List

Comment: @john Typo error. I updated it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I update the question with entire model class.

Comment: I recommend carefully comparing your model and JSON when you have problems like this.

Comment: Somewhere in your application, a `JsonSerializationException` is being swallowed without you noticing it. That shouldn’t happen and would have given you the necessary information on what to fix here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the class structure. The Codes should be in TraceEvent class not in its own class

```
public class TraceEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public TraceAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Codes")]
    public List<TraceCode> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

Remove below class

```
public class TraceCodes
{

    public TraceCodes()
    {
        Codes = new List<TraceCode>();
    }
    [JsonProperty("Codes")]
    public List<TraceCode> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`TraceEvent` has a property

```
public TraceCodes Codes { get; set; }
```

And `TraceCodes` is another object with a list of codes:

```
public List<TraceCode> Codes { get; set; }
```

This would mean there would have to be a structure like this:

```
{
    "TraceEvent": {
        "Codes": {
            "Codes": [
                { … },
                { … },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the `"Codes"` part is double. Instead, you need to modify your `TraceEvent` to have that list directly:

```
public class TraceEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public TraceAttributes Attributes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Codes")]
    public List<TraceCode> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

Btw. that should have actually resulted in a `JsonSerializationException`, so you should check whether that gets swallowed somewhere.

Comment: In his screenshot he has `EventContainer`, but he hasn't posted the definition.

Comment: Turns out he has a typo.

Comment: Oh well~ – Thanks for the heads-up john!